# SSH connection difference in Powershell and CMD

Tags: ssh, powershell, cmd.exe

The system is windows 10, with "OpenSSH client" feature, and no extra setting. I am curiousing why the ssh connection keeps longer in powershell than cmd, and how can I set it?

Comment: Please explain "...keeps longer" in more detail.

Comment: @grawity yeah, u r right! cmd ssh connection can only keep about 10 mins if there is no command input in between, but powershell can keep hours. Well I haven't test extractly how long the connection keeps, but with cmd it really bothers me, broke all the time, well with powershell, I just need to reconnect once or twice with in 8 hours. And I used to connect both local and remote server, they are all in the same situation